# Dynamically Fill Jenkins Choice Parameter With Git Branches In a Specified Repo

Tags: git, jenkins, parameters, branch

I have a parameterized Jenkins job which requires the input of a specific Git branch in a specific Git repo.  Currently this parameter is a string parameter.

Is there any way to make this parameter a choice parameter and dynamically fill the drop down list with the Git branches?  I don't want to require someone to maintain this choice parameter by manually configuring the drop down every time a new branch is created.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) will allow you to read the choices from a file.

Of course, now you have another problem: how to make sure the file is up-to-date (that can be done with a post-commit hook) and propagated to all the users (that can be done by placing it on a shared file server). But there may be better solutions.

Comment: We are using the [Extensible Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin) with a groovy script: `return [" "].plus(["powershell","(git.exe ls-remote -h http://review/Project)-replace '\\w{40}\\trefs/heads/'"].execute().text.tokenize())`. It's PowerShell since it's on Windows machine, but you can substitute with other tool for RegEx replacement. This will keep the list updated on every load without the need for external files.

Comment: @Stoinov I really like your solution. I am having trouble getting this to work on a linux server.

Comment: I have very little experience with linux, but you should be able to use any linux command that can replace the returned list from a git command.

Comment: great snippet, I'm missing ssh auth for git in my case ....

Comment: Thanks for sharing this idea, saved my day. I modified the code in my pipeline to set the default branch to master using the 'CascadeChoiceParameter' option.

Answer (score 95):

I tried a couple of answers mentioned in this link, but couldn't figure out how to tell Jenkins about the user-selected branch. As mentioned in my previous comment in above thread, I had left the branch selector field empty.

But, during further investigations, I found another way to do the same thing - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin
I found this method was a lot simpler, and had less things to configure!

Here's what I configured -

1. Installed the git parameter plugin
2. Checked the 'This build is parameterized' and added a 'Git parameter'
3. Added the following values: [image: Git Parameter plugin config in the job]
4. Then in the git SCM section of the job I added the same value mentioned in the 'Name' section, as if it were an environment variable. (If you read the help for this git parameter plugin carefully, you will realize this)
   [image: Branch Selector]

After this I just ran the build, chose my branch(Jenkins checks out this branch before building) and it completed the build successfully, AND by choosing the branch that I had specified.

Comment: Known Limitations / Bugs:
    git parameter plugin doesn't support Jenkins slave setup with git repos checked out only on slaves

Comment: I got all excited about this, but it's unfortunately plagued by a bug where it doesn't pass credentials to the git server. So if you need credentials (such as for private github repos), this won't work until JENKINS-28597 is addressed.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get branch name without 'origin/'. ${BRANCH_SELECTOR##*/} does not work when injecting variables.

Comment: Well for me, the chooser list itself contains origin/<branch-name>.. So that automatically comes into the $BRANCH_SELECTOR variable..

Comment: @AmokHuginnsson it is fixed and released in the beginning of July issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16290

Comment: @montss, sorry, that's not good enough. The plugin wouldn't present me with choice until I run the build _once_. Why? Why can't it perform the equivalent of `git ls-remote` against the repository and using the credentials specified in the job?

Comment: is it possible to use this plugin via Jenkinsfile instead of UI?

Comment: I haven't tried it @marengaz. Sorry. Do post your finding here if you manage to get it working.

Comment: I have selected the option Branch Or Tag. Tested with branches and works great. Also works great with Tags. The Git paramter plugin is great.

Comment: Note that you can't use `Lightweight checkout` with this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43818?focusedCommentId=299708&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-299708

Comment: How can you allow the user to select a repository and then branches in that repository

Answer (score 16):

I was able to achieve this result using the [Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in). I used the Dynamic Choice Parameter option and, for the choices script, I used the following:

```
proc1 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h ssh://user@server.com/path/to/repo.git"].execute()
proc2 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "awk '{print \$2}'"].execute()
proc3 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "sed s%^refs/heads%origin%"].execute()

all = proc1 | proc2 | proc3
String result = all.text

String filename = "/tmp/branches.txt"
boolean success = new File(filename).write(result) 

def multiline = "cat /tmp/branches.txt".execute().text
def list = multiline.readLines()
```

Comment: As an add on, I've found that ssh isn't always available but isnt necessarily needed. An alternative would be to use something like this:

`proc1 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h user@server.com:path/to/repo.git"].execute()`

This is especially useful information when working with github.

Comment: For some reason, the branch at the 8th position is always picked up. (I have about 19 branches). No matter which I select. Any idea if any more configuration needs to be done in the Jenkins job? Or there's something wrong with the plugin?
I have kept the 'branch' field empty.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a downstream issue, this just explains how to dynamically fill a parameter with your git branches. To use the branch in a build I typically name the parameter "branch" and then under "Source Code Management" (with Git selected) use "${branch}" (without the quotes) for the "Branches to build" "Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')" field. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, Looks similar to what I found with the Git Parameter plugin.(Posted my finding as another possible answer below). Thanks for this info though.

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately I am compelled to downvote because the Dynamic Parameter Plug-In has been suspended from Jenkins distribution due to a remote code execution vulnerability: https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-04-10/#dynamic-parameter-plugin

Answer (score 12):

Its quite simple using the ["Git Parameter Plug-in"](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter).

Add Name like "SELECT_BRANCH"   ## Make sure for this variable as this would be used later.
Then Parameter Type : Branch

Then reach out to SCM :
Select : Git
and branch specifier : ${SELECT_BRANCH}

To verify, execute below in shell in jenkins:

echo ${SELECT_BRANCH}

env.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: In my case, we work with feature branches. Jenkins should build automatically when someone pushes code to the feature branch as well. When the code is triggered by SCM changes, then the parameter will be empty. So I had to click Advanced and type ** in the Default Value box in order to have the automatic build as a result of a SCM change to work.

Answer (score 9):

For Me I use the input stage param:

1. I start my pipeline by checking out the git project.
2. I use a awk commade to generate a barnch.txt file with list of all branches
3. In stage setps, i read the file and use it to generate a input choice params

When a user launch a pipeline, this one will be waiting him to choose on the list choice.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('checkout scm') {
            steps {
                script {
                    git credentialsId: '8bd8-419d-8af0-30960441fcd7', url: 'ssh://jenkins@git.company.com:/usr/company/repositories/repo.git'
                    sh 'git branch -r | awk \'{print $1}\' ORS=\'\\n\' >>branch.txt'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('get build Params User Input') {
            steps{
                script{
                    liste = readFile 'branch.txt'
                    echo "please click on the link here to chose the branch to build"
                    env.BRANCH_SCOPE = input message: 'Please choose the branch to build ', ok: 'Validate!',
                            parameters: [choice(name: 'BRANCH_NAME', choices: "${liste}", description: 'Branch to build?')]
                }
            }
        } 
        stage("checkout the branch") {
            steps {
                echo "${env.BRANCH_SCOPE}"
                git  credentialsId: 'ea346a50-8bd8-419d-8af0-30960441fcd7', url: 'ssh://jenkins@git.company.com/usr/company/repositories/repo.git'
                sh "git checkout -b build ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
        }
        stage("exec maven build") {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'M3', mavenSettingsConfig: 'mvn-setting-xml') {
                   sh "mvn clean install "
                }
            }
        }
        stage("clean workwpace") {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the user will interact within the build:

[image: click the link to choose the branch to build]
[image: choose the branch in the following list]

Answer (score 6):

I am facing a similar problem here. 
Our users are migrating their jobs from freestyle to pipeline. They do not want Jenkinsfile stored in their repos(historical reason) and still want to use "Git Parameter" plugin

So we have to use use "Pipeline script" and develop a different plugin which works like "Git Parameter".

This new plugin does not integrate with SCM setting in the project. The plugin is at https://plugins.jenkins.io/list-git-branches-parameter

Hope it helps you as well

Comment: Thanks for this plugin! The only problem is we use declarative pipeline with two other parameters. If we configure this with the UI, it works, but after running it once, the parameter part is removed. How do you configure this in a declarative pipeline in the parameter section?

Comment: To give a more concrete example, something like this:
```parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "...", description: '...?', name: 'version')
        choice(choices: ['a', 'b'], description: '...?', name: 'environment')
        listGitBranches(parameterType: 'Branch', credentialId: '[id]', repositoryUrl: '[repoUrl]', name: 'branch')
}```

Answer (score 4):

I have a new response for this case: the easy way to solve this is having you jenkinsFile from source code.

Then you chose: this job have a git parameter

[image]

And and the Pipeline setup, unchecked the "Lightweight checkout" checkbox, this will perform a really git checkout on job workspace.

[image]

After, the parameter will be autopopulate by your git branch

Answer (score 2):

expanding on @malenkiy_scot's answer.
I created a new jenkins job to build up the file that is used by Extended Choice Plugin.

you can do the following (I did it as execute shell steps in jenkins, but you could do it in a script):

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:my/repo.git |grep refs/heads/* >tmp.txt
sed -e 's/.*refs\/heads\///' tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
tr '\n' ',' < tmp2.txt > tmp3.txt
sed '1i\branches=' tmp3.txt > tmp4.txt
tr -d '\n'  < tmp4.txt > branches.txt
```

I then use the Artifact deployer plugin to push that file to a shared location, which is in a web url, then just use 'http://localhost/branches.txt' in the Extended Choice plugin as the url.  works like a charm.

Comment: hmm.  is it a public repo?  can you share the git url?  I'd be curious to see why it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the same using the extended choice parameter plugin before mentioned by malenkiy_scot and a simple php script as follows(assuming you have somewhere a server to deploy php scripts that you can hit from the Jenkins machine)

```
<?php
chdir('/path/to/repo');
exec('git branch -r', $output);
print('branches='.str_replace('  origin/','',implode(',', $output)));
?>
```

or

```
<?php
exec('git ls-remote -h http://user:pass@repo.git', $output);
print('branches='.preg_replace('/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/heads\//','',implode(',', $output)));
?>
```

With the first option you would need to clone the repo. With the second one you don't, but in both cases you need git installed in the server hosting your php script.
Whit any of this options it gets fully dynamic, you don't need to build a list file. Simply put the URL to your script in the extended choice parameter "property file" field.

Comment: So you need this php script on a web server that has git installed + ssh credentials to access the git server. OK.
But how do you call this php script from the Extended Choice Parameter Plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
I wrote a little groovy script which does the trick
You should add a 'Dynamic Choice Parameter' to your job and customize the following groovy script to your needs :

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def gitURL = "git repo url"
def command = "git ls-remote --heads --tags ${gitURL}"

def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

if ( proc.exitValue() != 0 ) {
   println "Error, ${proc.err.text}"
   System.exit(-1)
}

def text = proc.in.text
# put your version string match
def match = /<REGEX>/
def tags = []

text.eachMatch(match) { tags.push(it[1]) }
tags.unique()
tags.sort( { a, b ->
         def a1 = a.tokenize('._-')
         def b1 = b.tokenize('._-')
         try {
            for (i in 1..<[a1.size(), b1.size()].min()) { 
                 if (a1[i].toInteger() != b1[i].toInteger()) return a1[i].toInteger() <=> b1[i].toInteger()
            }
            return 1
         } catch (e) {
            return -1;
         }
} )
tags.reverse()
```

I my case the version string was in the following format X.X.X.X and could have user branches in the format X.X.X-username ,etc...
So I had to write my own sort function.
This was my first groovy script so if there are better ways of doing thing I would like to know.

Comment: Beware of this script, running it in Dynamic Choice Parameter, had crashed my Jenkins (2.7, 2.8)

Comment: Can you tell why ? do you have a backtrace ? I have never tried it on 2.X version

Comment: it's probably due to System.exit() call (not related to Jenkins version)

Comment: I guess this does not support ssh creds for git? And System.exit should not be called, it kills the jenkins process?

Answer (score 1):

We can eliminate the unnecessary file read/write by using `text`. My complete solution is the following:

```
proc1 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', 
  "/usr/bin/git ls-remote --heads ssh://repo_url.git"].execute()
proc2 = ['/bin/bash', '-c', 
  "/usr/bin/awk ' { gsub(/refs\\/heads\\//, \"\"); print \$2 }' "].execute()
all = proc1 | proc2

choices = all.text
return choices.split().toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware to the fact that in the original question Jenkins pipeline was not mentioned, but if it is still applicable (using it), I find this solution easy to maintain and convenient.

This approach describe the settings required to compose a Jenkins pipeline that "polls" (list) dynamically all branches of a particular repository, which then lets the user run the pipeline with some specific branch when running a build of this job.

The assumptions here are:

- The Jenkins server is **2.204.2** (hosted on **Ubuntu 18.04**)
- The repository is hosted in a **BitBucket**.

First thing to do is to provide Jenkins credentials to connect (and "fetch") to the private repository in BitBucket. This can be done by creating an SSH key pair to "link" between the Jenkins (!!) user on the machine that hosts the Jenkins server and the (private) BitBucket repository.

1. First thing is to create an SSH key to the Jenkins user (which is the user that runs the Jenkins server - it is most likely created by default upon the installation):

   ```
   guya@ubuntu_jenkins:~$ sudo su jenkins 
   [sudo] password for guya:
   jenkins@ubuntu_jenkins:/home/guya$ ssh-keygen
   ```

   The output should look similar to the following:

> Generating public/private rsa key pair. Enter file in which to save the key
> (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa): Created directory '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh'. Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): Enter same passphrase again: Your identification has been saved in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa. Your public key has been saved in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. The key fingerprint is: SHA256:q6PfEthg+74QFwO+esLbOtKbwLG1dhtMLfxIVSN8fQY jenkins@ubuntu_jenkins The key's randomart image is:
> +---[RSA 2048]----+ | . .. o.E. | | . . .o... o | | . o.. o | | +.oo | | . ooX..S | |..+.Bo* . | |.++oo* o. | |..+*..*o | | .=+o==+. | +----[SHA256]-----+ jenkins@ubuntu_jenkins:/home/guya$

2. Now the content of this SSH key needs to be set in the BitBucket repository as follows:

- Create (add) an SSH key in the BitBucket repository by going to: `Settings --> Access keys --> Add key`.
- Give the key Read permissions and copy the content of the PUBLIC key to the "body" of the key. The content of the key can be displayed by running: `cat /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

3. After that the SSH key was set in the BitBucket repository, we need to "tell" Jenkins to actually USE it when it tries to fetch (read in this case) the content of the repository. NOTE that by letting Jenkins know, actually means let user `jenkins` this "privilege".

This can be done by adding a new  SSH User name with private key to the `Jenkins --> Credentials --> System --> Global Credentials --> Add credentials`.

- In the ID section put any descriptive name to the key.
- In the Username section put the user name of the Jenkins server which is `jenkins`.
- Tick the Private key section and paste the content of the PRIVATE key that was generated earlier by copy-paste the content of: `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. This is the private key which start with the string:`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with the string: `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. Note that this entire "block" should be copied-paste into the above section.

4. Install the Git Parameter plugin that can be found in its [official page here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/)
5. The very minimum pipeline that is required to list (dynamically) all the branches of a given repository is as follows:

   ```
   pipeline 
   { 
       agent any parameters
       { 
           gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH' 
       }
       stages 
       { 
          stage("list all branches") 
          { 
              steps 
              { 
                   git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", credentialsId: "SSH_user_name_with_private_key", url: "ssh://git@myCompanyBitBucketSite.com:port/myRepository.git" 
              } 
         } 
      } 
   }
   ```

NOTES:

- The `defaultValue` is set to `master` so that if no branches exist - it will be displayed in the "drop list" of the pipeline.
- The `credentialsId` has the name of the credentials configured earlier.
- In this case I used the SSH URL of the repository in the url parameter.
- This answer assumes (and configured) that the git server is BitBucket. I assume that all the "administrative" settings done in the initial steps, have their equivalent settings in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The following groovy script would be useful, **if your job does not use "Source Code Management" directly** (likewise "Git Parameter Plugin"), but still have access to a local (cloned) git repository:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def envVars = Jenkins.instance.getNodeProperties()[0].getEnvVars() 
def GIT_PROJECT_PATH = envVars.get('GIT_PROJECT_PATH') 
def gettags = "git ls-remote -t --heads origin".execute(null, new File(GIT_PROJECT_PATH))

return gettags.text.readLines()
         .collect { it.split()[1].replaceAll('\\^\\{\\}', '').replaceAll('refs/\\w+/', '')  }
         .unique()
```

See full explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810768/658497

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, This list dynamic branch names in dropdown w.r.t inputted Git Repo.

Jenkins Plugins required:

1. [Validating String Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/validating-string-parameter/)
2. [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)

**OPTION 1: Jenkins File:**

```
    properties([
        [$class: 'JobRestrictionProperty'], parameters([validatingString(defaultValue: 'https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git', description: 'Input Git Repo (https) Url', failedValidationMessage: 'Invalid Git Url. Retry again', name: 'GIT_REPO', regex: 'https://.*'), [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Select Git Branch Name', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'BRANCH_NAME', randomName: 'choice-parameter-8292706885056518', referencedParameters: 'GIT_REPO', script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return[\'Error - Unable to retrive Branch name\']'], script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''
                            'def GIT_REPO_SRC = GIT_REPO.tokenize(\'/\')
                            GIT_REPO_FULL = GIT_REPO_SRC[-2] + \'/\' + GIT_REPO_SRC[-1]
                            def GET_LIST = ("git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:${GIT_REPO_FULL}").execute()
                            GET_LIST.waitFor()
                            BRANCH_LIST = GET_LIST.in.text.readLines().collect {
                                it.split()[1].replaceAll("refs/heads/", "").replaceAll("refs/tags/", "").replaceAll("\\\\^\\\\{\\\\}", "")
                            }
                            return BRANCH_LIST ''
                            ']]]]), throttleJobProperty(categories: [], limitOneJobWithMatchingParams: false, maxConcurrentPerNode: 0, maxConcurrentTotal: 0, paramsToUseForLimit: '
                            ', throttleEnabled: false, throttleOption: '
                            project '), [$class: '
                            JobLocalConfiguration ', changeReasonComment: '
                            ']])
    try {
        node('master') {
            stage('Print Variables') {
                echo "Branch Name: ${BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
    }
    catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        print e.getMessage();
        print e.getStackTrace();
    }
```

**OPTION 2: Jenkins UI**

[image]

[image]

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, install this plugin: [Active Choice](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)

Then add `Active Choices Reactive Parameter`, Groovy Script：

```
def getGitBranchOptions(String gitRepo, String selectedBranch='') {
    def lines = ('git ls-remote -t -h ' + gitRepo).execute().text
    def branchArr = lines.readLines().collect {
        def brachName = it.split()[1]
        if (selectedBranch != '') {
            def pattern = /^refs\/heads\/$selectedBranch$/
            brachName = brachName.replaceAll(pattern, "refs/heads/$selectedBranch:selected")
        }
        brachName.replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
    }
    return branchArr
}

if (environment.equals('dev')){
  getGitBranchOptions("git@your_git_lab:group/gui.git", "dev")
} else if (environment.equals('test')){
  return ['test:selected','disabled_option:disabled']
} else if (environment.equals('production')){
  return ['master:selected']
}
```

Comment: It would be perfect if you could give a complete demo.