# Git branches/tags as a dropdown in paramaterized builds

Tags: cloudbees

We have a paramaterized build and we would like the branches and/or the tags of a git repository to be listed in a dropdown.  We have found this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin which seems to do about what we want, but since we use cloudbees we are unable to test it.  Has anyone used this plugin?  Any other ideas on how to accomplish this?

I have also seen this post: [Dynamically Fill Jenkins Choice Parameter With Git Branches In a Specified Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433105/dynamically-fill-jenkins-choice-parameter-with-git-branches-in-a-specified-repo)  Which may be another approach but again we can't test it as it's not in cloudbees by default.

Answer (score 1):

Git Parameter Plugin looks to be almost what you want, though it appears to currently only offer revision IDs and tags, whereas you would probably like to be offered branch names (another kind of ref). I think such a change would be easy to make.

The set of plugins available to you in a DEV@cloud Jenkins instance depends on your subscription level. If you need a specific plugin installed, open a support ticket.