# Automatically constructed drop down menu of available tags in parametrized build

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's say I have a Jenkins job with the parametrized build:

http: //SVN_SERVER/PROJECT/tags/${tags}

I would like to have a drop down menu for tags, rather than keying in the parameter manually.

I do not wish to construct the drop-down menu manually. I would like the drop down to be constructed from an automated scan of all the tags in project's SVN tag folder.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) with a custom Groovy script.

There is a nice example here for Jenkins and a dropdown with the Git branches here:
[Dynamically Fill Jenkins Choice Parameter With Git Branches In a Specified Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433105/dynamically-fill-jenkins-choice-parameter-with-git-branches-in-a-specified-repo)

You just have to replace the Git command with a SVN command to list all the tags.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The choice plugin may work, for me authentication with SSH keys did not.
I recommend this plugin:

https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/

You just add a parameter and the variable name you use in the git setup.
Works great for both tags and branches.