# Jenkinsfile Active choice parameter plugin(Dynamic git branch names)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to use Active Choices Reactive Parameter in my jenkinsfile with below groovy script:

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote -t -h https://USER:PASS@bitbucket.org/project_name.git").execute()
return gettags.text.readLines().collect { 
  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

How do I define this param in my jenkinsfile?

I have used below code :

```
properties([ 
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                  description: 'Select code branch name', 
                  name: 'code_release_branch', 
                  script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                  fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
                  script: 'return ["error"]'], 
                  script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
                  script: '''def gettags=("git ls-remote -t -h ssh://git@abc.com/code/code.git").execute()return gettags.text.readLines().collect{it.split([1].replaceAll('refs/heads/','').replaceAll('refs/tags/','').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}",'')}}''']]],
    ])
])
```

This gives "error" output in parameter

Please note that this groovy script is to get branch names from git dynamically

I have tried one more thing of putting this groovy script in Jenkins managed files and give the id as a parameter to script as below , but still same issue:

```
properties([ 
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
         choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
         description: 'Select code branch name', 
         name: 'code_release_branch', script: [
             $class: 'GroovyScript', 
             fallbackScript: [
                   classpath: [],
                   sandbox: false, 
                   script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
             ], 
             script: [
                   classpath: [], 
                   sandbox: false, 
                   script: '6cd2a674-c02d-44b0-87cb-b32f1fcdc0c3'
             ]
        ]],
    ])
 ])
```

Comment: Why not use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin?

Comment: @Joao .  But with this option, branch names will be available only after job is triggered. I want the user to select branch name and then run the job

Comment: Nope. Just add the  git repo and then the branch name will be available BEFORE you start the build.

Comment: I tried , did not work```properties([
    parameters([
        gitParameter(branch: '',
                     branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)',
                     defaultValue: 'master',
                     description: '',
                     name: 'BRANCH',
                     quickFilterEnabled: false,
                     selectedValue: 'NONE',
                     sortMode: 'NONE',
                     tagFilter: '*',
                     type: 'PT_BRANCH')
    ])
])
node {
    git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin.git'
}```

Comment: Is there anything that speaks against just using the `input` step (except your requirement "I need to use Active Choices Reactive Parameter")?

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65154953/6330670